# Nginx reverse proxy blocks large files to aiohttp server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, aiohttp

Nginx used as reverse proxy on the app server for all requests to python aiohttp web application. Browser client uploading a file with size 220kb and above to the server fails through nginx. Without nginx in the loop the file upload works fine. There is no response from nginx when uploading a larger file and it just hangs, nginx only responds after killing the POST method. I have tried modifying different client buffer sizes and timeouts but that did not help.
Tried different options with the following configuration settings -> client_body_in_file_only clean;client_body_buffer_size 32K;client_max_body_size 30M;send_timeout 300s.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have your setting, but here is the guide that may help you with aiohttp and NGINX. I use python-socketio and aiohttp and nginx:

1. Declare file upload size in web.Application(), this is easy to miss :)
   web.Application(client_max_size=1024**2*30)
2. Check if your NGINX has both HTTP and https and declare at both places:
   client_max_body_size 30M;

Uses Gunicorn or not does NOT matter but is highly recommended.

Hopes this helps.
Steve